# I need to get a list of fields in a document using LotusScript

Tags: document, lotusscript

I need to get a list of all the fields in a document then I can cycle through them and manipulate them as needed. I have done something like this in SSJS using doc.getItems() that returns a vector of all the fields, but there does not appear to be a similar LS function.
Any ideas?

Comment: In many cases (such as this one), the LotusScript equivalents of SSJS and Java methods that begin with 'get' are simply the base name of the method without the 'get'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Items" property of the NotesDocument class.